# How to add data and data flow in Ionic App using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, immutable.js

In *AngularJS* I want to create a birthday card list where I select my friends list from my *JSON* file and fill date of my selected friends.
I show my friends list in my `index.html` as

```
<!-- immutable scripts added -->
<script src="js/immutable.min.js"></script>

<ion-content class="has-subheader" >

  <!-- card list declaration -->
   <ul class="card">
      <!-- checkBox Declaration and filtering by search box -->
      <li class="item item-thumbnale-left" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">


           <!-- show friends list in cards  -->
            <input type="text" ng-model ="friend.Name" 
                ng-init = "friend.Name = item.Name" readonly/> 

            <!-- take a input field for taking friend b'day date --> 
              <div class="item item-input-inset">

                <!-- click a checkbox for add friend -->
                    <label class="checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-click ="saveOrDelBirthday(friend)" 
                         ng-show = "friend.Date" ng-model = "friend.check"/>
                    </label>

                     <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                         <input type="date"  placeholder="Enter Date" 
                            ng-model = "friend.Date" />
                    </label>

              </div>


      </li> 
   </ul>
  </ion-content>
```

when i click a *show* button then a new `list.html` shows all selected friends list with their birthday but
My selected friend list is not showing the list in
list.html file as

```
<ion-content>
   <ul class="card">
      <li class="item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in information">
         <div style="float: left">{{ key }}</div>
          <div style="float: center">{{ value }}</div>
      </li> 

   </ul>
    <label class="item">

   // this is for sending mail to me from my app
      <button class="button button-positive" type="submit" ng-click = "sendMailMe()" >Confirm</button> 
    </label>
```

I use immutable data structure for storing data with key value pair in `immutable.Map({})`;
I don't know where i'm wrong.

```
//my controller contain this method

$scope.information = {}; //storing data from map
var friendMap = Immutable.Map({}); //declaring Map for inserting data in key value pair
$scope.friendMap1;

//this section decide which operation perform

$scope.saveOrDelBirthday = function(friend){

  console.log(friend.check);

  if(friend.check){

   friendMap1 = friendMap.set(friend.Name,friend.Date); //insert friend information
  }
  else{
      friendMap1 = friendMap.delete(friend.Name); //delete friend information

  }

  information = friendMap1.toObject();    
  console.log(information);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$scope.information` expected by the `ng-repeat` directive isn't being defined in your controller or is returning an empty list/object.

Comment: but my '$scope.information' return map value in object form.

Comment: Try changing that last line to `$scope.information = friendMap1.toObject();`.

Comment: Thanks Armando, I changed _$scope.information = friendMap1.toObject();_ but this refrence contain only latest friend name and date when i click. Its not showing all selected friend name and date.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped!